# Solar System Model Python - List operation difficulty

Tags: python, list, vector, model, physics

this is my first post on here.
So I am trying to make a model solar system using visual python. I am defining each planet as a sphere, with radius, distance from sun, mass, and momentum variables. Then each planet (or body) is put into a list structure. As you can see currently I have a list with [earth, moon, mars] the sun is excluded for reason i will explain shortly.

So my problem comes when I'm trying to calculate the force caused by each body on each other body. What I am doing here is, for every ith value in the bodies list, the force between that and the nth body is calculated, the force on the ith body in the list bodies is the sum of the force between the ith body and each nth body from 0 to the end of the list. (i.e. the sum of all the forces due to every other body in the list)

This works correctly for the moon and mars (2nd and 3rd items in the list) but not for the earth. The output for the code below is,

```
<3.57799e+022, 0, 0>
<4.3606e+020, 0, 0>
<1.64681e+021, 0, 0>
<-1.#IND, -1.#IND, -1.#IND>   -  this is the total force on earth. 
<0, 2.07621e+027, 0>
<0, 9.83372e+027, 0>



from visual import *


AU = 149.6e9
MU = 384.4e6 # moon - earth orbital - radius
MarU = 227.92e9

G =6.673e-11

sun_mass =2e30
sun_radius =6.96e8
earth_mass =6e24
earth_radius =6.37e6
moon_mass =7.35e22
moon_radius =1.74e6
mars_mass = 6.41e23
mars_radius = 3390000
sun = sphere ( pos =(0 , 0 ,0) , velocity = vector (0 ,0 ,0) ,mass = sun_mass , radius =0.1* AU , color = color . yellow )
earth = sphere ( pos =( AU , 0 ,0)  ,mass = earth_mass , radius =63170000, color = color . cyan ,make_trail=True )# create a list of gravitating objects
moon = sphere ( pos =( AU+MU , 0 ,0)  ,mass = moon_mass , radius =17380000 , color = color . white, make_trail=True )
mars = sphere ( pos =( MarU , 0 ,0)  ,mass = mars_mass , radius = mars_radius , color = color . red, make_trail=True )

#initialise values:
we = 1.9578877e-7
wm = sqrt(G*earth.mass/3.38e8**3)
wma = 9.617e-5
dt = 3*60

earth.mom = vector(0,1.5e11*earth.mass*we,0)
mars.mom = vector(0, 9.833720638948e+27,0)
moon.mom = moon.mass*(earth.mom/earth.mass+vector(0,-3.48e8*wm,0))

bodies = [earth, moon, mars]

*N = 0
initialdiff = 0
for i in bodies:
        initialdiff = i.pos - sun.pos
        TotalForce = (G * i. mass * sun. mass * norm ( initialdiff )/ initialdiff . mag2)
        print TotalForce
        while N < len(bodies):
            if N!=i:
                diff = i.pos - bodies[N].pos
                Force = (G * i. mass * bodies[N]. mass * norm ( diff )/ diff . mag2) 
                TotalForce = TotalForce + Force
                i.mom = i.mom+TotalForce*dt
                N = N+1 
            else:
                N = N+1
print earth.mom
print moon.mom
print mars.mom*
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what working "correctly" means? ie. What are you expecting, and how is your code deviating from your expectations?

Comment: Hi sorry about that. So the part with issue is calculating net force on each object in the list. The list of vectors is the output of the code. The first three correctly show the force on each body in the list due to the sun (the intial force) then the next three vectors show the total net force (the force of the sun plus the force due to the other bodies in the list) however the vector output for earth isnt outputting numbers, and im confused as to what #IND actualy means. Im also confused as to why this result occurs, I can't see where the loop structure breaks.

Comment: -1.#IND is a special result which usually means zero divided by zero...  is it possible that this is occurring somewhere in your code?

Comment: I initialize my value for initialdiff which is used in the calculation of force where the product of a set of values is divided by initial diff. However just after 'for i in bodies' I set the value for initial diff to be 'initialdiff = i.pos - sun.pos' so this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I think it may have somehing to do with the fact that earth has the index in the list 0, and I have initialised N to be 0. The condition of the if statement is if N != i then. But for the case of the earth N is 0 and i is zero, so my intention with my if else statement is that it should be ignored and N = N + 1 and the loop continues, but I think there could be a potential error here, I just can not see it.

Comment: I can only recommend adding some print statements for the values of N and i in your loop and seeing if you can detect the error. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
'''Abel Tilahun HW 3 '''

# 02/03 / 2015

# make the necessary imports , visual import gives visual output, cos, sin and pi allows calculation of the positions
# in real time. The numpy arange import returns evenly spaced values within a given interval (angles)

from visual import *

from math import cos,sin,pi

from numpy import arange

# i used 'a' to magnify the sizes of the planet for better visualization
a=600

# the following line defines a sphere for the sun centered at the origin(0,0,0) all the other planets are positioned at a radial distance from this center.
Sun=sphere(pos=(0,0,0),radius=6955500*(a/100),color=color.yellow)

#the next 5 commands code the planets with their center being positioned at a distance of the radii of their orbit. Their radii are multiplied by a factor of 'a' to magnify them

Mercury=sphere(pos=vector(579e5,0,0),radius=2440*(a),color=color.red)

Venus=sphere(pos=vector(1082e5,0,0),radius=6052*a,color=color.orange)

Earth=sphere(pos=vector(1496e5,0,0),radius=6371*a,color=color.green)

Mars=sphere(pos=vector(2279e5,0,0),radius=3386*a,color=color.white)

Jupiter=sphere(pos=vector(7785e5,0,0),radius=69173*(a),color=color.cyan)

Saturn=sphere(pos=[14334e5,0,0],radius=57316*(a),color=color.magenta)

# the for loop calculates position of the planets by changing 
# the arange function increases the angle from 0 to pi with a small increment of 0.025 each time

for theta in arange(0,100*pi,0.025):

    rate(30)

    x = 579e5*cos(theta)

    y = 579e5*sin(theta)

    Mercury.pos = [x,y,0]


    x = 1082e5*cos(theta)

    y = 1082e5*sin(theta)

    Venus.pos = [x,y,0]


    x = 1496e5*cos(theta)

    y = 1496e5*sin(theta)

    Earth.pos = [x,y,0]


    x = 2279e5*cos(theta)

    y = 2279e5*sin(theta)

    Mars.pos = [x,y,0]


    x = 7785e5*cos(theta)

    y = 7785e5*sin(theta)

    Jupiter.pos = [x,y,0]


    x = 14334e5*cos(theta)

    y = 14334e5*sin(theta)

    Saturn.pos = [x,y,0]
```

Comment: You need to start paying attention to code formatting preview before posting. This and your other answer are well-nigh unreadable without editing.